# How to select the attribute that inside an attribute using queryselector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes, element

I want to learn how to select the `href` that contains the word 'groups'. That `href` is under or inside in `role="present"`. Please correct my code

```
document.querySelectorAll("[role=article[href*="groups"]]")[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: The problem is due to your mis-matched quotes. Use single quotes to delimit the outer string and double quotes within it: `querySelectorAll('[role=article[href*="groups"]]')`. I'd also suggest you use an editor with syntax highlighting to make errors like this easy to see.

Comment: It just looks like you need to switch from double quotes to single quotes. Which is clearly indicated by the in syntax highlighting.

Comment: Please show the HTML which you are querying as well.

Comment: The selector should be `"[role=article] [href*='groups']"`

Answer (score 0):

backtick "`" allows for ${} access to variables... the other way is to concat strings together.

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[role=article[href*=${groups}]]`)[1].innerHTML;
```